# Uninstall fedora broke my laptop

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I installed Fedora to a partition on my system running Ubuntu.  I formatted the Fedora partitions, but the Fedora grub still boots.

I can't boot Ubuntu without turning secure boot off.

The one problem I can think of is it removed the Ubuntu grub instead of the Fedora one.  How can I configure grub to boot Ubuntu again?

EDIT: i used a tool i had on ubuntu called boot-repair which reinstalls grub and it removed the fedora grub entry but no the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no need to reinstall GRUB. Run `sudo efibootmgr -v`: it will show you the UEFI NVRAM boot variables. There is probably still Fedora's boot entry as the first one in the boot order.

Each boot entry will be prefixed by `BootNNNN` where N is a number. Make a note of the numbers on Fedora's line, then use `sudo efibootmgr -b NNNN -B` to delete it. If Ubuntu was the first in the boot order before installing Fedora, it should become the first one again automatically. If not, use `sudo efibootmgr -o XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ` etc. (XXXX,YYYY and ZZZZ are the four-digit numbers of boot entries, as before) to set the boot order so that Ubuntu's entry is the first one, and any other entries as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks after doing this ubuntu was now in my bios menu and i put over fedora

Comment: If the answer was good, please click on the hollow green check-mark next to it to mark it as "accepted": this is even better than a regular upvote, and only you can do it for the answers to your questions. You might want to wait a few days before that to see if even better answers come up, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your signed Ubuntu boot loader has been overwritten by an unsigned one installed by Fedora. Please turn off secure boot in the BIOS and boot Ubuntu. Run the following command to install your boot loader again:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and turn secure boot back on.